# How to extract values from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I get a JSON strings through JSONP call. I just know that how the general structure of JSON is going to be but I do not know what will be the values and keys. The general structure will  be like this

```
 [
    {"key_name": "value"}, 
    {"key_name": "value"},
    {"key_name": "value"}
    ]
```

I do not know what will be inside curly brackes. How can I reach these values and change them to something like this

```
[
  {name: "key_name", y: value}, 
  {name: "key_name", y: value},
  {name: "key_name", y: value}
]
```

**where value is a number**
[example fiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/3woafcz7/6/)

Comment: in this case, just start with a "for" and then use a "foreach" for cover each object, thats all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on the array of objects. Fetch the array of keys of an object using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```js
var x = [{
  "key_name1": "25"
}, {
  "key_name2": "452"
}, {
  "key_name3": "32"
}];

var new_x = x.map(function(el) {

  return {
    "name": Object.keys(el)[0],
    "y": +el[Object.keys(el)[0]]
  };

});

console.log(new_x);
```

Comment: How can I remove commas around name, y and the value is going to be a number

Comment: @Imo i can not see any comma.

Comment: @Imo and i am not doing any typecasting on `y value here`, so if it is number it will be a number and won't get converted in string.

Comment: not sure why but the commas are not removed when I try to do it with your code, fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/3woafcz7/8/

Comment: @Imo can you tell me the exact output which you want?

Comment: the exact output form the example fiddle would be [{name:"China", y: 67},{name:"germany",y: 87},{name:"India",y:86},{name:"Nepal",y:567},{name:"France",y:12}]

Comment: So name, y and the number without commas

Comment: @Imo commas or apostrophes?